# Angular 2-12 Mobile Camera Capture

Tags: angular, mobile, camera

I'm looking for a way to use the mobile camera to capture a photo and upload it to a server in Angular 2+. Is it possible to do it?

I can find a lot of uploading files tutorials but not even one which tutoring how to access the mobile camera and use the captured photo.

Comment: Yes you can.Try this [link](https://tutorialzine.com/2016/07/take-a-selfie-with-js). this is in java script but you can easily change it into an angular component

Answer (score 17, accepted):

OK, so I finally got what I need.
In the .html file:

```html
<input type="file" capture="camera" accept="image/*" id="cameraInput" name="cameraInput" (change)="onFileSelected($event)">
<button type="button" (click)="onUpload()">Upload File</button>
```

in the .ts file:

```html
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';
  selectedFile = null;

  onFileSelected(event)
  {
    this.selectedFile = event.target.files[0];
  }

  onUpload()
  {
    console.log(this.selectedFile); // You can use FormData upload to backend server
  }
}
```

Use "selectedFile" variable to whatever you need to do with your photo.

Note: It only works on iOS6+, I have checked on android and it works well.